# Very strange pulseaudio behavior

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, pulse-audio

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, and currently no audio devices are showing up. When I try to run pulseaudio via the command line, I get this error https://pastebin.com/FLCmqFLG

For some reason tho, MPD still plays audio.

If anyone could help me that would be great, because I'm completely lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MPD probably still plays audio using ALSA.

Your log contains this error:

```
E: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: You apparently ran out of inotify watches, probably
because Tracker/Beagle took them all away. I wished people would do their homework
first and fix inotify before using it for watching whole directory trees which is
something the current inotify is certainly not useful for. Please make sure to drop
the Tracker/Beagle guys a line complaining about their broken use of inotify.
```

Try [disabling](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346211/tracker-store-and-tracker-miner-fs-eating-up-my-cpu-on-every-startup/348692#348692) [Tracker](https://askubuntu.com/questions/722664/how-to-stop-a-file-or-folder-from-being-indexed-in-gnome).

Comment: weird, because my MPD is configured to use pulse. How do I disable tracker?

Comment: @lorazepam I added two links to my post.